# Question about special orthogonal Lie group construction

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, transformation

Working through homework and I run into this problem:

> Suppose the Lie group $SO^{+}(2,2)$ is presented as the group of all transformations in its associated space. How do you determine whether a given 4x4 transformation matrix is an element of the group?

I'm slightly familiar with the $SO^{+}(1,3)$ Lie group, but have almost no experience with group theory as a whole. So far, I seem to remember the conditions require orthogonality between coordinates, preservation of the orientation (of subgroups?), and elements with a determinant of 1, but still feel like I'm missing something. I expect given a matrix representation of the form:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & 0 & 0\\
c & d & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & e & f\\
0 & 0 & g & h\end{array} \right) $

Do I need to ensure the determinants of the components

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{array} \right) $
and $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
e & f \\
g & h \\
\end{array} \right) $

are related  in a certain way to prevent orientation shifts (such as reflections), or do I only need to pay attention to the total determinant of a transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $SO(2,2)$, You should check that it preserves the quadratic form $-x^2-y^2+z^2+w^2$, and that the matrix has determinant one. I guess the $+$ means that the transformation preserves both orientations, meaning that in you example both smaller determinants have to be equal to one.